# Cannot use GoogleSignInClient.silentSignIn() to retrieve an id token in an OkHttpClient Authenticator

Tags: android, kotlin, google-api, google-oauth, okhttp

In my Android app written in Kotlin, I use Google Sign-In for authorization, and JWT tokens for authentication with my back end API. Both my JWT tokens and Google Sign-In's JWT token expire after 1 hour.

I want my app to re-authorise with Google Sign-In and re-authenticate with my API when a request to my back end API fails with a 401 error, so I added an authenticator to the OkHttpClient.

However, when I run the code below, the silentSignIn task locks up permanently and does not respond on the line `val result = Tasks.await(task)`.

Am I missing something obvious? I can't find any reason as to why silentSignIn() would lock up in when called from the authenticator.

Elsewhere, I do not use `Tasks.await(task)`, as there I use an `OnCompleteListener` to update the UI, update the `apiToken` and `googleToken` variables, however in the code below I wanted to update the `apiToken` and `googleToken` when the request failed, without requiring the other code in my project to re-fire the request to the back end API.

**TLDR: I want to call GoogleSignIn.silentSignIn() in an OkHttpClient Authenticator, get the token, and retry the request immediately, but my app freezes on Tasks.await.**

```kotlin
    val RC_SIGN_IN = 9001
    var apiToken: String? = null
    var googleToken: String? = null

    val client: OkHttpClient = OkHttpClient
        .Builder()
        .authenticator(object : Authenticator {
            override fun authenticate(route: Route?, response: Response): Request? {
                return if (response.code == 401) {
                    // Configure sign-in to request the user's ID, email address, and basic
                    // profile. ID and basic profile are included in DEFAULT_SIGN_IN.
                    val gso =
                        GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                            .requestEmail()
                            .requestIdToken("token_goes_here")
                            .build()

                    // Build a GoogleApiClient with access to the Google Sign-In API and the
                    // options specified by gso.
                    val googleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this@MainActivity, gso)
                    val task = googleSignInClient.silentSignIn().addOnCompleteListener {
                        val result = it.getResult(ApiException::class.java)
                        googleToken = result?.idToken
                    }.addOnFailureListener {
                        val signInIntent = googleSignInClient.signInIntent
                        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN)
                    }

                    if (task.isSuccessful) {
                        googleToken = task.result?.idToken
                    } else {
                        try {
                            /**** The following line is where the routine locks up: ****/
                            val result = Tasks.await(task)
                            googleToken = result?.idToken
                        } catch (ex: ExecutionException) {
                            // task failed
                            Log.e(TAG, "authenticate error:{ex}")
                        } catch (ex: InterruptedException) {
                            // an interrupt occurred while waiting for the task to finish
                            Log.e(TAG, "authenticate error:{ex}")
                        }
                    }
                    apiToken = getApiToken(googleToken)
                    response.request
                        .newBuilder()
                        .header("Authorization", "Bearer $apiToken")
                        .build()
                } else {
                    null
                }
            }
        }
        )
        .build()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging I have found the answer. For the sake of anyone else in a similar boat, I will document the problem and solution below:

My suspicions grew when I was starting to have a similar bug with the Google Play Billing Library locking up in a similar manner. An investigation showed that I was calling my API get() code from a runBlocking { } context. Google used the same thread as OkHTTP was using, and so runBlocking caused all network I/O outside of OkHTTP to be blocked until OkHTTP was finished.

The solution was to remove runBlocking wherever possible, loading the data via launch {} asynchronously, and use notifyDataSetChanged() to update the RecyclerView when that is done. I haven't been able to remove runBlocking completely, but it is used so little now, and I have reworked the Task.await() block so that it times out, and calls the intent on timeout:

```kotlin
try {
    val result = Tasks.await(task, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    googleToken = result?.idToken
} catch (ex: ExecutionException) {
    // task failed
    Log.e(TAG, "authenticate error:{ex}")
    val signInIntent = googleSignInClient.signInIntent
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN)
} catch (ex: InterruptedException) {
    // an interrupt occurred while waiting for the task to finish
    Log.e(TAG, "authenticate error:{ex}")
    val signInIntent = googleSignInClient.signInIntent
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN)
} catch (ex: TimeoutException) {
    // an timeout occurred while waiting for the task to finish
    Log.e(TAG, "authenticate error:{ex}")
    val signInIntent = googleSignInClient.signInIntent
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN)
}
```

A better solution would be to implement ViewModels (https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel), which I recommend for a new project, but because of a tight deadline, I have not been able to do that in this release.